# Javascript object show null but after click to see there are value but cannot access

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-hooks, ref

I am developing the project by using ReactHook and I have problem with `React.createRef()`. I suffer this problem and I want to know what is the situation like this called? and how to fix it? As in the figure 1, it shows that the value of the object is null but when I click to see it. There are value there but I cannot access its value by the key because I cannot access the key of null.
[image: Figure 1.After I tried to <code>console.log</code> variable googleMap]
Figure 1.After I tried to `console.log` variable googleMap

```js
import { Map, GoogleApiWrapper } from "google-maps-react";
import { GOOGLE_API_KEY } from "../../key.js";

const storePage = ({google}) => {
  const googleMap = React.createRef();
  console.log(googleMap.current.map);
  ...
```

Figure 2.I just use `React.createRef()` in order to access  component

```js
...
return (
<Map
            google={google}
            zoom={16}
            initialCenter={{ lat: yourLocation.lat, lng: yourLocation.lng }}
            style={{ height: "20rem" }}
            ref={googleMap}
          ></Map>)
}
const enhance = compose(
  GoogleApiWrapper({ apiKey: GOOGLE_API_KEY }),
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
);

export default enhance(StorePage);
```

Figure 3.I want to access the  component for getting the value like figure 1
[image: Figure 4.But when I access the value by the key(like this <code>googleMap.current.map</code>), the error occurs like this figure]
Figure 4.But when I access the value by the key(like this `googleMap.current.map`), the error occurs like this figure

Comment: is this a class or a function component? At the time you console.log, the component is probably not rendered yet. it won't have a value until it's been rendered in the DOM. If you are in a class component you can catch this in the componentDIdMount lifecycle. If it's a functional component you can do this in a useEffect hook

Comment: a function component

Comment: Please do not show pictures of code. Show code. [Stackoverflow has straight-forward markup for this](/editing-help#syntax-highlighting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from 'react';

const googleMap = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(googleMap && googleMap.currentValue)
}, [googleMap])
```

Notice I used the hook for creating the ref. What this will do is run a use effect whenever the value of the googleMap ref changes. IE: Before and after the ref is rendered.